# Customise tinymce without content css option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce

I am using react with tinymce. I would like to customise it without the content_css property because I tried a lot and it just would not work. Can the component be given a class? How do I give inline styles to it

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want to do and what doesn't work?

Comment: I want change the background change font color etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline styles cannot be given. Content css uses the relative path to the css file.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative which is more react friendly is react-rte